# Why aren't my name servers updating?

Tags: nameserver, a-record, ttl

I have had hundreds of domains over the years, and generally, the 24 to 48 hour rule applies. Sometimes even much quicker. I've learned that the registrar you use affects it a lot. GoDaddy usually takes minutes, whereas hostgator generally takes 24 to 48 hours; however, now I am using 1&1 IONOS. It has been 4 days since I updated the Name Servers and they still haven't propagated. My host is GoDaddy. So I am pointing my Name Servers to GoDaddy. I have tried http://dns.squish.net as recommended on another (older) StackExchange question. And that didn't give literally ANY information, except that it "failed".

Can someone possibly identify the problem for me as I really need to get this website up and running? I would appreciate it. http://insidethereport.com

Also, GoDaddy nor IONOS customer service knows what they're doing. I have called GoDaddy, they said call IONOS. IONOS said, call GoDaddy. It's like a never ending while loop lol

Comment: You're pointed at GoDaddy's nameservers. They are not returning an A record for the domain.

Comment: "the 24 to 48 hour rule applies. " There is certainly no such rule. Never. Nowhere. The DNS works not top down but bottom up and is governed by TTLs. Hence this does not depend on the registrar but only the DNS provider you are using (which could be the registrar or not, but those are 2 separate jobs).

Answer (score 1):

According to WHOIS, your domain is registered with "1&1 IONOS SE" but your DNS servers are Godaddy

```
Name Server: NS15.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
Name Server: NS16.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
```

[WHOIS Search](https://www.godaddy.com/whois/results.aspx?domain=insidethereport.com)

Did you just specify these nameservers without setting up a ZONE with godaddy? That will not work. You need to setup a zone on your provider (at this point, cloudflare would be easiest imho) and then point your nameservers to the servers provided by the provider at your registrar.

Registrar != DNS, although the same company can provide both services (and often does)

Comment: How can I setup a zone when the domain options aren't available yet for GoDaddy? They'll only be available AFTER the nameservers are updated, correct?

Comment: I did add the domain as an addon domain if that's what you mean?

Comment: After finally talking to a 2nd person from GoDaddy, they resolved the issue. Something to do with the IP Address. Either way, minutes after talking to this person, my domain was propagated at 12 of the servers on whatsmydns.net and live on my browser. Although, Los Angeles might not see my website now lol But it's starting to work, just wanted to let you know so I think I'm good.

Comment: DNS doesn't propagate, though. It's cached.

Comment: @EsaJokinen correct, do you have a better word for 'cache expired and serving correct results from cache on this caching resolver'?

Comment: It's not just the term, but ironically using "propagation checkers" causes the current value to be cached on multiple servers, making it actually to take longer for the caches to expire. If there's a delay from web control panel to the authoritative name servers, one should be `dig`ging it directly from there, instead of voluntarily caching the old value everywhere. That's why the false conception on how DNS works causes problems.

Comment: @EsaJokinen lol I've said that for years, 3600 TTL will bite you in the ass if you check it (resolver) before the NS is serving

Comment: @EsaJokinen and JacobEvans: I agree but any good DNS troubleshooting should always start by asking the authoritative nameservers concerned and never any recursive. Only after everything is checked on the authoritative (and the parent's authoritative) then can queries try any recursive (eitler local or global). Doing things like that also promote not spoiling caches, especially those you can't control, with bad values.

Comment: Whois is not a good source for DNS troubleshooting except in a very narrow specific cage (the clientHold/serverHold statuses). So to check nameservers it is better to use the DNS and ask the parent (the registry) what it thinks the delegation points to.

Comment: Ok, well I appreciate it. But there was an actual problem I couldn't fix alone. When I called the host I was pointing to, they had to make some change with the IP address. Within minutes it began propagating.